# The Hahn-Banach Extension theorem Elaboration

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, hahn-banach-theorem

I am following "Lecture Notes on Functional Analysis" by A.Bressan.  After the proof of the Hahn-Banach Extension theorem there is the following picture to demonstrate the theorem. It is not immediate for me to see the theorem geometrically. So, I wondered to have elaboration\explanation on the following depiction.

[image: c]

Comment: Can you identify the spaces involved in that picture? Note that the $z-$ axis (not explicitly shown) is the real line, to which $p$ and $ f$ map.

Comment: yes , I have a problem about the F function , I cannot see that it is a linear functional on X.